# I need to find all instances of a phrase in a file and then print a sorted list of the next word after that phrase

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to run a program where I find all of the times that the phrase "Invalid user" appears and then have the program find the username for each invalid user entry and have it print off a list of users in a sorted manner alphabetically.  Unfortunately, every time I run the program it prints the entire line and not just the user names.  This is an example of the file that I am wanting to search through:

```
May 26 06:25:01 instance-1 CRON[19549]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 26 06:38:14 instance-1 sshd[19783]: Connection closed by 210.187.175.103 port 60536 [preauth]
May 26 06:39:05 instance-1 sshd[19797]: Invalid user backups from 182.254.146.167 port 58682
May 26 06:39:05 instance-1 sshd[19797]: input_userauth_request: invalid user backups [preauth]
```

In the third line, you can see "Invalid user" followed by "backups" which is the user name I am wanting to have printed at the end.  Here is the code that I have been working with, but it prints off "Invalid user:" and then the entire line after that:

```
invalid_users = []
substr = "invalid user".lower()
with open('auth.log', 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        if line.lower().find(substr) != +1:
            invalid_users.append("Invalid user" + ": "+ line.lstrip("/n")) 

for users in invalid_users:
    print(users)
```

I wish I was good at Python, but I am very inexperienced with it, and have not had much luck learning it yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem - pattern matching in text - can be solved using [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (implemented in the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module in Python's standard library).

Let's say we have the lines from the question collected in a list:

```
>>> print(lines)
['May 26 06:25:01 instance-1 CRON[19549]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root', 'May 26 06:38:14 instance-1 sshd[19783]: Connection closed by 210.187.175.103 port 60536 [preauth]', 'May 26 06:39:05 instance-1 sshd[19797]: Invalid user backups from 182.254.146.167 port 58682', 'May 26 06:39:05 instance-1 sshd[19797]: input_userauth_request: invalid user backups [preauth]']
```

Let's import the re module and define a pattern to be matched

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'[Ii]nvalid user\s+(\w+)\s+'
```

The pattern to be matched is:

- either an "I" or an "i", followed by "nvalid"
- followed by at least one whitespace character
- followed by a subpattern in brackets: at least one character that might make up a word (a username in this case)
- at least one whitespace character

Now we search for the pattern in each line:

```
>>> matches = [re.search(pattern, line) for line in lines]
```

What do we find?

```
>>> matches
[None,
 None,
 <re.Match object; span=(40, 61), match='Invalid user backups '>,
 <re.Match object; span=(64, 85), match='invalid user backups '>]
```

Let's loop through the good matches and print the match for the subpattern:

```
>>> for match in filter(None, matches):
...     print(match.group(1))
... 
backups
backups
```

Putting it all together, it might look like this:

```
import re 

pattern = r'[Ii]nvalid user\s+(\w+)\s+' 

with open ('auth.log', 'rt') as myfile: 
        matches = [re.search(pattern, line) for line in myfile]
    for match in sorted(filter(None, matches)): 
        print(match.group(1))
```

Comment: While that seems logical, I am not understanding how to actually get that to occur.  I keep getting syntax errors in my code.  This is what I have done:

    mylines = []
with open ('auth.log', 'rt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        mylines.append(line)
    for element in mylines:

        import re
pattern = r'[Ii]nvalid user\s+(\w+)\s+'
matches = [re.serach(pattern, line) for line in lines
           for match in filter(None, matches):
            print(match.group(1))

Comment: @StephenDangel I added a more complete example